# MySQL Query with Multiple Dates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull some activity reports for an application based on date ranges (number of "Stars" for each post)

It has a post table that includes and account id, and an "affiliate" table that ties that id to an account.

I know that I can do:

```
SELECT
posts.affid,
affiliates.name
sum(posts.stars) AS SEPT_2012
from posts
JOIN affiliates on posts.affid = affiliates.id
WHERE posts.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-10-01'
group by affid
```

That will pull a result that has the affiliate ID, Name and total "stars" from September. A single month

However, I'd like to do a pull that goes back and gets numbers for August, July, June and May that would display in a single query result (so the result would include affid, name, SEPT_2012, AUG_2012, JUL_2012...etc). Essentially, doing subqueries for those other date ranges, I assume.

Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to `GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM timestamp)` (in addition to whatever else you want to do). Of course it will not get you the `SEPT_2012`, `AUG_2012`, etc. columns, but the data will be there.

Answer (score 0):

While you won't be able to dynamically create the columns, you can "fake" them and use a `UNION` for each date range. Inside each `UNION`, you select `0` for the *other* date columns and the `SUM()` for the correct column.

Something similar to this should work:

```
SELECT
    posts.affid,
    affiliates.name,
    sum(posts.stars) AS SEPT_2012,
    0 AS AUG_2012,
    0 AS JUL_2012
from
    posts
    JOIN affiliates on posts.affid = affiliates.id
WHERE
    posts.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-10-01'
group by affid

UNION (
    SELECT
        posts.affid,
        affiliates.name
        0 AS SEPT_2012,
        sum(posts.stars) AS AUG_2012,
        0 AS JUL_2012
    from
        posts
        JOIN affiliates on posts.affid = affiliates.id
    WHERE
        posts.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-08-01' AND '2012-09-01'
    group by affid
)
UNION (
    SELECT
        posts.affid,
        affiliates.name
        0 AS SEPT_2012,
        0 AS AUG_2012,
        sum(posts.stars) AS JUL_2012
    from
        posts
        JOIN affiliates on posts.affid = affiliates.id
    WHERE
        posts.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-08-01'
    group by affid
)
```

**UPDATE** (to combine all results for each `affid` on a single row)

Per a comment, you would like to combine the results for each `posts.affid` on a single row with all of the data in each column. You can achieve this by putting an outer-query around the *full* query above and then using `GROUP BY affid` again. With this, you should have a single row for each `affid` and all of the columns as requested. I've updated the above query to select `0` for each empty column instead of `null` for "nicer" output too:

```
SELECT affid, name, SEPT_2012, AUG_2012, JUL_2012 FROM (
    ... full query above ...
) AS q
GROUP BY affid
```

**UPDATE**

To get the sum of all "stars" from all subqueries, the outer select statement works with:

```
  SELECT affid, name, sum(SEPT_2012), sum(AUG_2012), sum(JUL_2012) FROM (
    ... full query above ...
) AS q
GROUP BY affid
```

Comment: "Faking it" is TOTALLY fine by me. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I think that's close. It gets the data, but creates a different row for each month's select statement. BUT... I'm getting closer. Thanks

Comment: @user1714388 I've updated my answer to show how you can merge the results into single rows for each `affid`. Hopefully that will give you want you'd like =]

Comment: BIG help! Thanks. I had to make one other small change to the initial select statement:

SELECT affid, name, sum(SEPT_2012), sum(AUG_2012), sum(JUL_2012) FROM...


That was necessary to keep the initial "0" in the first subquery from being the end result in the output.

Thanks for sending me in the right direction!